# Linker Errors on OS X "ld: framework not found SFML"

Tags: c++, macos, linker-errors, sfml

I trying to compile my shell file but it shows

***ld: framework not found SFML
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)***

Actually I installed all SFML in the file and the system. I don't know what's wrong with it cuz it can be complied before.

I updated system to OSX EL Capitan. Is it the reason?

The sh file screenshot and directory screenshot:

[image]

Comment: That's not enough information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the sfml zip from sfml-dev.org again. Then look in its `SFML-2.4.2-osx-clang/Frameworks` folder. Copy everything in there to `/Library/Frameworks/`

Answer (score 0):

The [§Installing SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/start-osx.php#installing-sfml) is what you're looking for.

> Copy the content of Frameworks [from the downloaded SDK] to /Library/Frameworks.

Comment: I have finished all the instructions on the SFML page and copied the content of frameworks to the /library/frameworks. But it's still failed:(

Comment: Sorry to hear that, but this means you did something wrong. Try maybe from scratch.